# Elasticsearch query does not return records for present data

Tags: elasticsearch

We have small elasticsearch index of around 1 million records. The records in the elasticsearch looks something like the following.

```
{
  _index: gobzersearchindex
  _type: searchField
  _id: V-BzuHMgSui1l-vxlqTeTg
  _score: 3.614574
  _source: {
    gobzId: 198992
    productAttributes: [
      {
        name: untag_words
        value: yebhi59413 puma bikini
      }
      {
        name: brand
        value: Puma
      }
    ]
    imageOptimized: 0
    multiColor: 0
  }
}
```

When I try to query on the index, I am finding some unusual behavior. I was trying the following query.

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "match" : {
        "productAttributes.value" : {
          "query" : "adidas",
          "type" : "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get no results for the above query when I search for query string `adidas`, but the same query returns results when I use query string like `puma`, `benetton` and other brands. I was unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Edit:
The following mapping was used to create the index

```
PUT /gobzersearchindex/
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "test_filter_stopwords_en": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords_path": "stop_en.txt"
        },
        "test_filter_snowball_en": {
          "type": "snowball",
          "language": "English"
        },
        "test_filter_synonyms_en": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms_path": "synonyms_en.txt",
          "ignore_case": true,
          "expand": true
        },
        "test_filter_ngram": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 30
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "test_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "test_filter_stopwords_en",
            "test_filter_synonyms_en",
            "test_filter_snowball_en"
          ],
          "char_filter": "html_strip"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "searchField": {
      "properties": {
        "itemSearchableField": {
          "index": "analyzed",
          "type": "string",
          "store": "yes",
          "include_in_all": false,
          "analyzer": "test_analyzer"
        },
        "productAttributes.value": {
          "index": "analyzed",
          "type": "string",
          "store": "yes",
          "include_in_all": false,
          "analyzer": "test_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the adidas data is present ? Can you post a sample of adidas brand ?

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick response. There are a lot of adidas brand data. More than 7000 of them are present. Here is the sample

Comment: {
_index: gobzersearchindex
_type: searchField
_id: JyNtiBWqQWCKOZ36CRckDg
_score: 5.504997
_source: {
gobzId: 865348
productAttributes: [
{
name: untag_words
value: myntra263418mymtra "adidas unisex water bottle" 
}
{
name: multicolor
value: 0
}
{
name: colors
value: pink
}
{
name: brand
value: Adidas
}
]
imageOptimized: 0
multiColor: 0
}
}

Comment: can you add the mapping you are using to index your data to the question?

Comment: John : I have edited the question to add the mapping into it.